# Quickblox, video chat sample in a web client

Tags: quickblox

My question is about the web client api of quickblox. There are several examples of video chat in all platforms except for a web client. Does the web api supports video chat out of the box?

I will appreciate a sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video Chat for web is unavailable by now. QuickBlox expects to release it in the nearest future, hopefully in a week. Feel free to follow our [blog](http://quickblox.com/blog/) to learn about all updates.